# Как изменить встроенный редактор в mc на vim?

Tags: debian, vim, mc

Пробовал такие решения:

1. Через [опцию](https://askubuntu.com/a/16782) `use internal editor`
2. С помощью `export EDITOR="vim.basic"` в `~/.profile`
3. С помощью запуска `select-editor` в командной строке mc.

Есть ли более надёжные способы изменить редактор по умолчанию в mc на vim?

Comment: По идее первых двух пунктов хватить должно. Но ещё update-alternatives для надёжности можно.

Comment: Немного холиварно но всеже спрошу. Что такого умеет mc, что не умеет vim? Почему не использовать только его?

Comment: в виме также можно смотреть файлы, лазить по каталогам. Но как то mc более для этого предназначен. Но есть ещё vifm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью `update-alternatives` выбираем `vim.basic` для просмотра и редактирования файлов:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
sudo update-alternatives --config view
```

В `~/.config/mc/ini`:

```
use_internal_view=0
use_internal_edit=0
```

И в `~/.bashrc` добавляем:

```
export EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim"
```

Answer (score 0):

Так же еще нужно проставить опции в самом mc. Жмем F9 - далее Options - далее Configuration и в открывшемся окошке убираем опции "Use internal edit"/"Use internal view" - OK.